# Who partial specialization may inherit from a class template

Tags: c++

I am trying to make partial specialize class that may inherit from a class template, But compile gives error. Code and error is given below.

```
template<class t>
class a{};

template<class t>
class b<t*>:a<t>{}; 

main(){
   a<int> obj1;
   b<int*> obj2; 
}
```

Error:

```
error: 'b' is not a template
error: expected class-name before '{' token
```

When i replace b class code with this code

```
class b:public a<t>{};
```

it works.

Answer (score 2):

In order to partially specialize a template, you must already have created the primary template. If you want to define `b<T*>` you must first define `b`.

That is, the following is an error:

```
template<class t>
class a{};

template<class t>
class b<t*>:a<t>{};
```

This is valid:

```
template<class t>
class a{};

// Primary template
template<class t>
class b{};

// Partially specialized for pointers
template<class u>
class b<u*>:a<u>{};
```